# freeform pro paginate problem

Tags: solspace-freeform

I want to use freeform pro entries tag to list all attendees. But seems to be a problem to combine freeform:paginate together with a table. I need to loop around the 'TR' tag.
It shows the paginate links well, but both top and bottom links are above my table. I tried the variable pair {freeform:all_form_fields} but this doesn't work

Anyone who nows a solution here?
Thank you.
Pixelman.

```
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="200">Name</th>
                    <th>Forum Account</th>
                    <th width="">Company</th>
                    <th width="">Job title</th>
                    <th width="">Country</th>
                    <th width="">Type</th>
                    <th width="">Show</th>
                    <!-- <th width="">confirmed</th> -->
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
{exp:freeform:entries form_name="regtest" sort="asc" orderby="last_name" limit="100" paginate="top" search:listings="not Don't share my details" search:confirmed="y"}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{freeform:field:first_name} {freeform:field:last_name}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" target="_blank">{freeform:field:mibusouser}</a></td>
                    <td>{freeform:field:company}</td>
                    <td>{freeform:field:jobtitle}</td>
                    <td>{freeform:field:country}</td>
                    <td>{freeform:field:registrartype}</td>
                    <td>{freeform:field:listings}</td>
                    <!-- <td>{freeform:field:confirmed}</td> -->
                  </tr>
                  {freeform:paginate}
                  <p>
                    Page {freeform:current_page} of {freeform:total_pages} pages &nbsp; {freeform:pagination_links}
                  </p>
                  {/freeform:paginate}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: I thought I solved it but still the same problem…

Answer (score 0):

Pagination with `paginate="both"`, for example, will place the code you have between `{freeform:paginate} ... {/freeform:paginate}` right **above and below** your main `{exp:freeform:entries}` code. In your case, the `<p>...</p>` content would show right after your opening `<tbody>`, and right before your closing `</tbody>` tag. HTML tables do not correctly display data that isn't wrapped in  or , because it's not the correct way to build an HTML table. A simple look at your HTML source code would reveal this.

You can handle this in different ways. If you want the pagination to be part of your table, starting with your code above you could use:

```
{freeform:paginate}
<tr>
   <td colspan="7">Page {freeform:current_page} of {freeform:total_pages} pages &nbsp; {freeform:pagination_links}</td>
</tr>
{/freeform:paginate}
```

This will place a row above and below your table rows, but still inside your `<tbody> ... </tbody>` tags, so everything is semantically correct.

Alternatively, if you want your `<p>...</p>` to show up completely above and below the `<table>...</table>` code, you will need to put your opening and closing table code *inside* `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag pair.

You might ask:

> *But, wouldn't the opening and closing `<table>` tags loop more than once if they're inside `{exp:freeform:entries}`?*

You can make these display once using a conditional along with 
`{freeform:count}`:

```
{exp:freeform:entries /* your other parameters */}
    {if freeform:count == 1}
      <table>
         <thead>
             <tr>
               <th width="200">Name</th>
               <th>Forum Account</th>
               <th width="">Company</th>
               <th width="">Job title</th>
               <th width="">Country</th>
               <th width="">Type</th>
               <th width="">Show</th>
               <!-- <th width="">confirmed</th> -->
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
    {/if}

    // ... the rest of your table ...

    {if freeform:count == freeform:total_results}
         </body>
      </table>
    {/if}

    {!-- 
         == Pagination == 
         This will be extracted from the tag pair and
         placed above and below the exp:freeform:entries tag 
    --}
    {freeform:paginate}
       <p>
          Page {freeform:current_page} of {freeform:total_pages} pages &nbsp; {freeform:pagination_links}
       </p>
    {/freeform:paginate}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Same principle as when using other EE tags, such as `{exp:channel:entries}`.

Comment: thank you I'll give it a try ;) For now I used a workaround via jQuery.      $(function(){
   var $paginationNav = $('.paginate').clone();
   $('.paginateBottom').html($paginationNav);
 });